# Switching bezierpath to follow SpriteKit swift

Tags: spritekit, beziers, path

I am trying to make it so that a SKShapeNode follows a UIBezierPath. Then when the screen is tapped it switches to another UIBezierPath to follow. I have this functionality working except that when the screen is tapped the shape node moves back to where it started. I want it so that when the screen is tapped the circle does not go back to where it starts. Here is my code.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //screenWidth and screenHeight
    screenWidth = view.bounds.width
    screenHeight = view.bounds.height

    // Set up the circle track
    let trackWidth = screenWidth/3

    let circleTrack = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - trackWidth/2, screenHeight/2  - trackWidth/2, trackWidth, trackWidth), cornerRadius: 100)
    let shapeTrack = SKShapeNode(path: circleTrack.CGPath, centered: true)
    shapeTrack.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)
    shapeTrack.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.addChild(shapeTrack)

    //Outside track
    outsideTrack = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake((screenWidth/2 - trackWidth/2) - trackWidth*0.08, (screenHeight/2  - trackWidth/2) - trackWidth*0.08, trackWidth + trackWidth*0.16, trackWidth + trackWidth*0.16), cornerRadius: 100)

    //Inside track
    insideTrack = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake((screenWidth/2 - trackWidth/2) + trackWidth*0.08, (screenHeight/2  - trackWidth/2) + trackWidth*0.08, trackWidth - trackWidth*0.16, trackWidth - trackWidth*0.16), cornerRadius: 100)

    //Set the default track
    track = outsideTrack

    // Create the ball
    circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
    //circle.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    self.addChild(circle)

    //Move the circle
    let followPath = SKAction.followPath(track.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, speed: 200.0)
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(followPath)

    //Move the circle
    circle.runAction(repeatForever)
}

//Movement of circle
func movemementOfCircle(){
    if track == insideTrack{
        track = outsideTrack
    }else{
        track = insideTrack
    }

    //Actions
    circle.removeAllActions()
    //Move the circle
    let followPath = SKAction.followPath(track.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, speed: 200.0)
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(followPath)

    //Move the circle
    circle.runAction(repeatForever)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to define two followPath's. e.g.

```
let followPath1 = SKAction.followPath(track.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, speed: 200.0)
let followPath2 = SKAction.followPath(track.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, speed: 200.0)
```